# Why do I get an E488 error when printf .vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, error

I'm trying to automate the creation of .vimrc using this command:

```
printf "\n# Funcionar como vim y no como vi\nset nocompatible\n\n# Colorear sintaxis\nsyntax on\ncolorscheme sienna\n\n# Otros seteos\n# Más info, desde vim poner: :help '<comando>'\nset backspace=2\nset wrapmargin=8\nset ruler\nset number\n" > ~/.vimrc
```

But I get this error: `E488` in lines 2, 5 9 and 10.

The .vimrc file after the execution is:

```
# Funcionar como vim y no como vi
set nocompatible

# Colorear sintaxis
syntax on
colorscheme sienna

# Otros seteos
# Más info, desde vim poner: :help '<comando>'
set backspace=2
set wrapmargin=8
set ruler
set number
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `#` is not the comment character in vim.  It is `"`.  For example, `" This is a comment`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#` is not a comment character, `"` is. So it should read:

```
" Funcionar como vim y no como vi
set nocompatible

" Colorear sintaxis
syntax on
colorscheme sienna

" Otros seteos
" Más info, desde vim poner: :help '<comando>'
set backspace=2
set wrapmargin=8
set ruler
set number
```

Yeah, it's a strange choice, but it is what it is.

The easiest way to fix this in your shell command is to switch the shell quotes to `'`:

```
printf '\n" Funcionar como [...]'
```

[Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) is a good resource to start learning Vim.